# Last Working Day is showing null while on weekend

Tags: t-sql

Here is my code but its showing null while today is friday. But I would like to get last working day.

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
--Below is the param you would pass
DECLARE @dateToEvaluate date=GETDATE();

--Routine
DECLARE @startDate date=CAST('1/1/'+CAST(YEAR(@dateToEvaluate) AS char(4)) AS date); -- let's get the first of the year

WITH 
tally(n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 FROM sys.all_columns),
dates AS (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS dt_id, 
            DATEADD(DAY,n,@startDate) AS dt,
            DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(DAY,n,@startdate)) AS dt_name
    FROM tally
    WHERE n<366 --arbitrary
    AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(DAY,n,@startDate)) NOT IN (6)
    AND DATEADD(DAY,n,@startDate) NOT IN (SELECT CAST(HolidayDate AS date) FROM Holiday)),
curr_id(id) AS (SELECT dt_id FROM dates WHERE dt=@dateToEvaluate)
SELECT d.dt
FROM dates AS d
CROSS JOIN
curr_id c
WHERE d.dt_id+1=c.id
```

Comment: Can you state more clearly what it is you're trying to calculate?

Comment: For you kind information , I am using this query for getting last working day production. but while its weekday then showing null value for this reason my report is not working on weekday like friday.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. Are you trying to calculate the previous week day (Monday through Friday) given a date input? Such that inputting 2015-03-20 would produce 2015-03-19 and inputting 2015-03-23 would produce 2015-03-19?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will take any date and "walk backward" to find the previous week day (M-F) which is not in the @holidays table.

```
declare @currentdate datetime = '2015-03-22'

declare @holidays table (holiday datetime)
insert @holidays values ('2015-03-20')

;with cte as (
  select
    @currentdate k
  union all
  select
    dateadd(day, -1, k)
  from cte
  where 
    k = @currentdate
    or ((datepart(dw, k) + @@DATEFIRST - 1 - 1) % 7) + 1 > 5 --determine day of week independent of culture
    or k in (select holiday from @holidays)
)
select min(k) from cte
```

Comment: Actually, my coding is working fine. Its showing last working day . As example , today is saturday and my query return 19-03-2015 (Thursday) but when i execute the query on friday its showing null value.Friday is our  weekend. While i visit my website on friday it showing error for that query but it ok on others day.

Comment: Yes, you are right . your code is awesome. It's Working . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `dates` table doesn't have any FRIDAY dates in it.  Change the `NOT IN (6)` to `NOT IN (1, 7)`.  This will remove Saturday and Sundays from the dates table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . but while today is Saturday or Sunday then getting null value. For you kind information , I am using this query for showing last working day production. but while today is weekday then not showing my report. on other days the report is working fine.

Comment: What do you want to have returned on Saturday or Sunday?

Comment: Actually, my coding is working fine. Its showing last working day . As example , today is saturday and my query return 19-03-2015 (Thursday) but when i execute the query on friday its showing null value.Friday is our  weekend. While i visit my website on friday it showing error for that query but it ok on others day.

Comment: I would like to get thursday if it not in holiday.